# How do I run a command when a certain entity is at a certain position

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have tried `/execute if entity @e[name=Example] positioned x y z run command`. But when that execute command is used the output always happens no matter what

Answer (score 1):

The `positioned` argument of the execute command will run the command from that position in the world. The `if entity` argument will make it so that the command will only run if there are any existing (loaded) entities that match the selector.

What you might want to do is `/execute as @e[name="Example",x=<yourX>,y=<yourY>,z=<yourZ>] run <command>`.